# Is it possible to develop Analysis solely from Peano's axioms

Tags: calculus, analysis, peano-axioms

...and a few definitions on the way?

When I studied Calculus using Spivak's book It was clearly shown
that, in order to prove some fundamental theorems (intermediate value theorem being one of them),
one had to assume an additional property of numbers (namely the least upper bound property).
Other postulated properties included the field axioms and 3 more axioms (needed for the inequalities).

But then I skimmed over "Grundlagen der Analysis" by Landau (which was in the recommended reading by the way)
and he developed the reals using Dedekind cuts assuming only Peano's axioms - the way I saw it.
I also read on Wikipedia that the set of Dedekind cuts has the least upper bound property.
So it seems possible that we can get from Peano's axioms all the way to theorems in analysis 
(or am I missing some additional assumptions?)

If it is true that Peano's axioms are all we need, then I want to know how far we can take them...in general (not just real analysis).
Also is there an *elegant* way to prove the field axioms for real numbers from Peano's axioms?

Comment: How many definitions is 'a few'?

Comment: you know...addition, multiplication...cuts...limits...derivatives...integrals

Comment: So you're assuming integration, something that you'd need to rigorously develop? :-/

Comment: No - I'm assuming I would develop everything I need to state it's definition

Comment: There is a scary and fun area of foundations called "reverse mathematics" that looks into how little or how much you need to be able to develop parts of analysis.

Comment: There are many different types of integrals. Which would you choose?

Comment: Considering I just finished reading Spivak...Reimann integral (better said Darboux- easier to find the integrability condition)

Comment: It should be possible to deconstruct anything within a finitistic framework, because at the end of the day we're still finite state machines that can only perform a finite number of operations.

Comment: @user258704 See my answer and addendum. You do not have to simply define these objects and hope for the best. As far as I know, you can actually construct all of them from the natural numbers as defined by Peano's Axioms by using subsets, Cartesian products, power sets and choice functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't true that "Peano's axioms are all we need". Landau's beautiful account involves some set theory (the Dedekind cuts are *sets* or *pairs of sets* of rational numbers). There are many elegant ways of getting to the real numbers from the integers, but they all need a bit more than Peano's postulates. One of my favourites is [this paper by Behrend](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01187947#page-1), which shows how the additive structure can be defined first and the multiplicative structure derived from it.

Comment: thanks - I'll look more into both behrend's paper and Landau's book (i will try to keep record of the zfc axioms he uses). I also noticed he used ordered pairs (i think, he didn't mention explicitly) to define ratios...so yeah should have seen that coming ;)

Comment: The mathematical content of this paper was paid for by the German taxpayer, and thousands of libraries have paid for the printing costs; but sixty years later we are asked $ 40.00 for the opportunity to read a copy.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I understand your annoyance about paying Springer Verlag, but as regards the German taxpayer please  read http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Extras/Behrend_LMS_obituary.html? Behrend was a second world war refugee.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thank you for letting me read this obituary.

Comment: LOL. The German taxpayers are busy bailing out Greece and need all the help they can get.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: so you read the obituary, but you haven't retracted your statement that Behrend's work was funded by the German taxpayer. Was Germany funding mathematical research in Australia in the 1940s and 1950s?

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, I was able to construct the set of *positive* real numbers as Dedekind cuts starting from Peano's axioms and using the rules of first-order logic and some set theory (my own formulation based *very* loosely on ZFC).

I began with Peano's axioms as follows:

1. $1\in N$
2. $\forall x\in N:[ S(x)\in N]$
3. $\forall x,y\in N:[S(x)=S(y)\implies x=y] $
4. $\forall x\in N:[S(x)\ne 1]$
5. $\forall P\subset N: [1\in P \land \forall x\in P:[
       S(x)\in P] \implies \forall x\in N:[x\in P]]$

I then *constructed* the usual addition ($+$) and multiplication ($\times$) functions on $N$, and constructed the set $Q^+$ of positive rational numbers such that:

$\forall x:[x\in Q^+ \iff x\subset N^2 \land \exists a,b\in N: \forall c,d:[(c,d)\in x \iff a\times d = b\times c ]]$

**Note: By *constructed*, I do not simply mean *defined*. I mean that I actually prove the existence of these constructs using the axioms of set theory and the rules of logic.**

I was eventually (after thousands of lines of formal proof) able to construct the usual addition ($+$) and multiplication ($\times$) functions, and the usual ordering ($<$) on $Q^+$, and the set $R^+$ of positive real numbers such that:

$\forall x:[x\in R^+\iff x\subset Q^+$

$ \land \exists y:[y\in x]$

$ \land \exists y \in Q^+:[ y\notin x]$

$\land \forall y\in x: \forall z\in Q^+:[z<y\implies z\in x]$

$ \land \forall y\in x:\exists z\in x: [y<z]] $

From set theory, I had to be able to construct subsets, power sets, Cartesian products (ordered pairs and triples only) and functions of one or two variables. I also made use of set equality (extensionality). **I made no use of any other aspects of set theory.**

**Addendum**

Here are links to to key proofs for constructing the positive real numbers:

- Constructing the [addition function $+$ on $N$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructAddN.htm) (the positive integers) (727 lines)
- Constructing the [ordering $<$ on $N$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructLTN.htm)  (53 lines)
- Constructing the [multiplication function * on $N$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructMultN.htm) (736 lines)
- Constructing the [set of positive rational numbers $Q^+$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructQPos.htm) (91 lines)
- Constructing the [ordering $<$ on $Q^+$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructLTQpos.htm) (51 lines)
- Constructing the [set of positive real numbers $R^+$](http://dcproof.com/ConstructRPos.htm)  (70 lines)

Comment: Very impressive. Could you provide a link to your work.

Comment: @martycohen  As promised, see Addendum. I left out a lot, e.g. proving associativity, commutativity, etc. but these proofs show how I was able to construct the positive real numbers starting from Peano's Axioms. The addition and multiplication proofs are tedious monsters, but you can get the gist of them from the introductions.